# How to send a string from a chrome extension to C++ WIndows socket

Tags: javascript, visual-c++, google-chrome-extension

I have tried looking for methods to communicate . For instance, Mozilla provides XPconnect for bindings between Javascript to XPCOM. Does Chrome have any such APIs?

Comment: https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/nativeMessaging

Answer (score 0):

As Gael mentions, [Native Messaging](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/nativeMessaging) is your nearly only way.

You need to write (and distribute separately) a Native Host module for the extension - that Chrome can launch and pass your data to. It will serve as a proxy between your extension and COM.

You could also make a service that exposes a local web or WebSockets interface that the extension can call. This way, you don't need Native Messaging, but it makes for some security concerns.

In either case, you need an external "proxy" (or "glue", if you prefer that metaphor) software.